# Any suggestions to decide whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1} \ln (4n+1)}{n(n+1)}$ converges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

First, I verified if the general term $\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}  \ln (4n+1)}{n(n+1)}$ tends to $0$, and it does: $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2n-1}}{n} \frac{\ln(4n+1)}{n+1} = 0$$
Which other test could I use?
I have tried the comparison test, however couldn't find any other series which converges and is an upper bound for my series (or a series which diverges and is a lower bound for my series).
Does someone have a suggestion for what I could use?

Comment: Can you think of upper bounds for the logarithm that would simplify the expression?

Comment: It can get smaller than any $n$th-root for large n (such as $\sqrt {4n+1}$) but I have tried this without success...

Comment: Well, if a square root doesn't work, have you tried a cube root?

Comment: For large $n$s the general term is $\ll\frac{1}{n^{7/5}}$ hence the series is absolutely convergent by the p-test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sum u_n$ the given series. It is not difficult to see that

$$n^\alpha u_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\quad \forall 1<\alpha<\frac32$$
so

$$\exists n_0,\quad \forall n\ge n_0,\; u_n\le \frac1{n^\alpha}$$
hence the series $\sum u_n$ is convergent by comparison with the Riemann series.

Comment: that was very ingenious

Comment: @ElCid Actually it is a standard argument. See http://web.mit.edu/dvp/18.01A/topic12.pdf Asymptotic comparison test.